# Flutter dynamic type argument

Tags: flutter, generic-type-argument

I'm trying to pass a dynamic type argument to the `Provider.of<T>(context)`

### My Code

```
class CustomInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Type stateClass;

  CustomInputField({
    Key key,
    this.stateClass,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<stateClass>(context);

    return TextFormField(
      key: state.key,
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

But this gives me following error:

> The name 'stateClass' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
>   Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'stateClass'.

Anyone knows how to correctly do this?

It could be that this is not a good practice, or maybe it's even impossible. But thing is, I would like to make a single `CustomInputField` widget for all the inputfields in my app. I'm using the `ChangeNotifierProvider` class from the Provider package and would like to pass different states to this `CustomInputField` widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a type to generic dynamically in Dart. The only way to do it is to have switch/if-else block and return objects with different type in generic.

Comment: So I first made an enum class called StateClassEnum. I then made an extension to that enum containing a switch-method called ```getProvider(BuildContext context)``` with a return type of ```dynamic```. The switch-method returns the Provider.of<StateClass> for each StateClassEnum-case. In the build-method of my widget I call ```var state = stateEnum.getProvider(context);```. The only thing I'm not sure of is the ```dynamic``` return type. Is it correct to use ```dynamic```?

Comment: @SimonartM if your bloc classes are inherited from the same class, you can make return type of this class. However, I don't think it will be helpful enough or easy to use. I don't know how good it applies for your architecture, but maybe try using making one common bloc class that will be a bit different depending on enum value or something like that. Dart doesn't allow many things to do with generics.

Comment: Ah of course, I should first Inherit my blocClasses from a super-class. That's a very good point. Furthermore, trying to make one bloc class will be pretty hard, I think I'll just write more code than I would delete. I'll have to have a good thought about how to architecture this, I'm trying/thinking different things with interfaces and mixins, I'll post an update-comment when I'm through this. Thanks for the support anyway.

Comment: Small update, I used the enum class along with extending my states from a super-class. I've got almost everything in my super-class, and the small differences I've put in the individual state-classes. So now my ProviderBuilder which takes buildcontext and the enum can return a Provider of a fixed class instead of dynamic. Maybe there is a better solution, but for now this works. Thanks for your advice.